# How to join and indent checked item depends on names/ids in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm populating set of value in textarea where if checkbox name is **category** is checked it will output a newline then if the checkbox name is **product** then indent. And remove the details if the parent product or category are not checked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var elems = $('input:checkbox');
 elems.on('change', function() {
  $('#list').val(
   elems.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
   }).get().join("\n\t")
  );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<table border="1">
 <tr><td>Category</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Details</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Category 1" name="category" /> Category 1</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName A" name="product" /> ProductName A</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail A-1" name="detail" /> ProductDetail A-1</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td rowspan="2"><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName B" name="product" /> ProductName B</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-1" name="detail" /> ProductDetail B-1</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-2" name="detail" /> ProductDetail B-2</label></td></tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3"><label><input type="checkbox" value="Category 2" name="category" /> Category 2</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName A" name="product" /> ProductName A</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail A-1" name="detail" /> ProductDetail A-1</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td rowspan="2"><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName B" name="product" /> ProductName B</label></td>
  <td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-1" name="detail" /> ProductDetail B-1</label></td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td><label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-2" name="detail" /> ProductDetail B-2</label></td></tr>
</table>

<textarea id="list" rows="10" cols="45" ></textarea>
 </form>
```

my current script returning a set of a newline items:

```
Category 1
    ProductName A
    ProductDetail A-1
    ProductName B
    ProductDetail B-1
    ProductDetail B-2
    Category 2
    ProductName A
    ProductDetail A-1
    ProductName B
    ProductDetail B-1
    ProductDetail B-2
```

Would it possible to view like this as expected? or do you have any idea to meet this output?

```
Category 1
    ProductName A
        ProductDetail A-1
    ProductName B
        ProductDetail B-1
        ProductDetail B-2
Category 2
    ProductName A
        ProductDetail A-1
    ProductName B
        ProductDetail B-1
        ProductDetail B-2
```

Comment: In your html, the check box productName A and product B are after each other, then you have details, so how to know that detail A-1 is for product A, and detail A-2 and A-2.1 are for product B ?

Comment: Hi sir.. I've edited the html code. thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = $('input:checkbox');

    elem.on('change', function() {
        $('#list').val(
            elem.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                if(this.name == 'product') {
                    return "\t" + this.value
                }
                if(this.name == 'detail') {
                    return "\t\t" + this.value
                }
                return this.value;
            }).get().join("\n")
        );
    });
});
```

I tested it and it seems working ;)

To be able to check if the parent element is checked, you need to have the information about your parent element in the input: for example, using data-parent attribute, so you will have:
html

```
<tr>
        <td rowspan="3">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="Category 1" name="category" /> Category 1</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName A" name="product" data-parent="Category 1"/> ProductName A</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail A-1" name="detail" data-parent="ProductName A" /> ProductDetail A-1</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductName B" name="product"  data-parent="Category 1"/> ProductName B</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-1" name="detail"  data-parent="ProductName B"/> ProductDetail B-1</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="ProductDetail B-2" name="detail"  data-parent="ProductName B"/> ProductDetail B-2</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

JS

```
    function checkParent(type, value) {
        return $('input:checkbox[name="' + type + '"][value="' + value + '"]:checked').length;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var elem = $('input:checkbox');
        var parent;

        elem.on('change', function() {
            $('#list').val(
                elem.filter(':checked').map(function() {
                    if(this.name == 'product') {
                        // check for parent category
                        parent = $(this).data('parent');
                        if(checkParent("category", parent)) {
                            return "\t" + this.value;
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                    if(this.name == 'detail') {
                        parent = $(this).data('parent');
                        category = $('input:checkbox[name="product"][value="' + parent + '"]').data('parent');
                        if(checkParent("product", parent) && checkParent("category", category)) {
                            return "\t\t" + this.value;
                        } else {
                            return '';
                        }
                    }
                    return this.value;
                }).get().join("\n").replace("\n\n", "\n")
            );
        });
    });
```

When it is a **product** we check the parent category, and when it is a **detail**, we check the product and also the category.

The last **replace** is needed to prevent having empty lines.

Comment: Woaw! it works like a charm! thanks sir! now my problem is to remove the details if the parent product or category are not checked

Comment: @mrrsb your are welcome :)  I just edited my answer to solve the parent problem

Comment: problem solved! accepted answer! kudos Sir B. Assem your the man! :)